# Utilize IPhone GPU to 100%

Tags: objective-c, ios

For testing purposes I want to utilize the Iphone GPU to 100% in the background.
I'm not sure how to do this as I haven't done any GPU progamming.

Comment: While your app is not running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a simple answer since the GPU is a complicated piece of hardware that performs many functions and can have many bottlenecks.

You can draw a lot of triangles in your draw function for starters. 
On top of that you can have a complicated pixel shader with more than a few lines of code. Complicated math in the shader can easily become the bottleneck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess if I draw a lot of triangles I could utilize (is that even the correct word?) the GPU to almost 100%. But is there any sample code about the complicated pixel shader?